# Dimension mismatch between input data and trained data when using conv1D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have tried to build my first CNN using Conv1D, as i deal with time series data.  My target is to make compression for input_data of 1501 shape. The x_train shape is (550, 1501) and I increased it's dimension to fit the model.

However, the compiler complains:

> ValueError: A target array with shape (550, 1501, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1500, 1) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

This is the code

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, UpSampling1D, Flatten, Input
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers, Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

#(1,128,1)
input_data = Input(shape=(1501,1))
fil_ord = 3
# Eecode
encode  = Conv1D(2000,  fil_ord, activation='relu', padding='same')input_data) 
encode = MaxPooling1D( 2 )(encode)
encode = Conv1D(750,   fil_ord, activation='relu', padding='same')(encode)

# Decode

decode  = Conv1D(750,  fil_ord, activation='relu', padding='same')(encode)
decode = UpSampling1D( 2)(decode)
decode = Conv1D(1,   fil_ord, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(decode)


model = Model(input_data, decode)


model.summary()

from numpy import zeros, newaxis
x_train1=x_train[:,:,None]

batch_size = 128
epochs = 10
# Optimizer
sgd = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

# compile
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=sgd)
# train
history = model.fit(x_train1, x_train1, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=2,shuffle=True)
```

The model.summary() output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the `decode` output dimension at `axis=1`, i.e., `1500` which is different from the target `x_train1` dimension of `1501`.

This is happening due to *this chain* of *max-pooling* and *upsampling* operations: `1501 -> 750 -> 1500` where `MaxPooling1D` ignores one additional element while down-sampling and outputs features of dimension `750` at `axis=1` which is not recovered from up-sampling operation with `UpSampling1D`.

Hence, the target (`x_train1`) and the predicted (`decode`) outputs differ in shape because of which we cannot compute the loss.

Two approaches that could be used to solve this are:

- **Crop** the target (`x_train`'s) dimension in `axis=1` to match that of the `decode`'s, i.e., `1500`. Here's one way to do this:
  `history = model.fit(x_train1, x_train1[:,:-1,], batch_size=batch_size, ...)`
- **Pad** the output obtained from `decode` with (say) `0`'s, to match dimension of `x_train`, i.e., `1501`. One way to do this is by using [ZeroPadding2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d) layer on `decode`:
  `ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,0),(0,1),(0,0)))(decode)`